# How do I check which Operating System (OS) is used in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

Is there something similar to [Ruby's OS gem](https://github.com/rdp/os) which allows me to check if I am running on Mac, Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible but Crystal is complied, so this can be done at compile time. The internals use [flags](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/compile_time_flags.html) which seem to be set [here](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/cdb4b31fe5f139b4df4d2ca915c456e728558692/src/compiler/crystal/semantic/flags.cr).

```
{% if flag?(:linux) %}
  # Linux
{% elsif flag?(:darwin) %}
  # Mac
{% elsif flag?(:win32) %}
  # Windows
{% end %}
```

Comment: environment variables might help as well, FWIW